# Webbrowser makes complete halt whenever faulty certificate is found

Tags: opera, certificate

Recently I happened upon something ***very*** irritating:

[image]

After a short minute of google, I found an [answer](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=162808):

Apparently there was a problem with the certificate of the server. Now, I may not know anything about how certificates work, but this felt odd. *Very odd.*

And to top it off, this happened in *both* Chrome and Opera, my two favorite browsers.

Sure, I understand if they complain whenever you happen upon a broken and/or faulty certificate. But I still want the option to actually visit the site, regardless of any certificates.

#### **My question/s:**

1. Is there any way to overcome this problem?
2. What the heck did they think with when they made this "feature"? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to just issue a warning and then let you continue on your own?

**EDIT:** FYI, the site that got me into posting this question was [dolce-gusto.se](https://www.dolce-gusto.se/), a site I know I can trust.

Comment: See: [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3804370/225906), to [This organization's certificate has been revoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802982/this-organizations-certificate-has-been-revoked) on StackOverflow

Comment: Interesting, apparently the same problem, but on the other side [of the server].

Answer (score 1):

IE9 does the same, and reports "This organization's certificate has been revoked. Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.", and doesn't give the option of continuing (Error, vs. Warning). So maybe you CAN'T trust them. :)

According to MS: "This website’s security certificate has been revoked" :: "Do not trust this website. This error message often indicates that the security certificate was obtained or used fraudulently by the website. The encryption key that is specified in the certificate might have been compromised or the user listed in a certificate does not have authority to use it (for example, the company was sold). The certification authority that issued the certificate keeps a list of revoked certificates and that list is checked by Internet Explorer."

IE9 gives you the ability to turn off this check in the Advance Options.

In Opera I believe you can disable the `OCSP Validate Certificates` setting located in the `operaprefs.ini`, under the section called `[Security Prefs]`, to trun off Certification checking (not a good idea). :)

Comment: Well, I don't think I want it completely turned off. I'd rather have it check the certificates and warn me, but let me enter if I wanted to.

Comment: How that error is treated is going to be browser specific, and from what I can tell, they all work basically the same way. YMMV. :)